# For completed tickets, display the four with the shortest time to completion (the time between date requested and date completed.)

Tags: mysql

I'm using mySQL and I can't figure out how to calculate the following question:

4. For completed tickets, display the four with the shortest time to completion (the time between date requested and date completed.)

Comment: Usually for homework questions, you'll get help if you ask a question in a such a way that we can help you *learn*.  For that, you need to add details about the tables in question, including the column names and types, etc.  Be as detailed as you can be, and show us what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: The table has 5 columns; description, location, daterequested, datecompleted, techname. The date format is 2015-02-10 for daterequested and datecompleted. The location is TC 118, techname is O. Singh.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my answer:

```
SELECT techname, MIN(datecompleted)
FROM ticket
GROUP BY techname
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Look on the manual page for how to subtract date_requested from date_completed.